# jquery, mouseenter to move down image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, move

I am new to JS, I am hardworking to improve my skills with JS, so far everything went well, till now, I have to move the img in the nav , when mouse enters it moves down and when it leaves back up.
https://www.youtube.com/embed/8qKRf0cg3Co

I have tried different things to get it done, but im stuck now.
Now, when I moveover the img, it keeps going down and when I leave it wont be back in place.

`$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.foto').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({marginTop: '+=50'}, 200);
    });
    $('.foto').mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).animate({marginBottom: '-=50'}, 200);
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `marginTop` in `mouseleave` not `marginBottom`

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.foto').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({marginTop: '+=50'}, 200);
    });
    $('.foto').mouseleave(function (){
        $(this).animate({marginTop: '-=50'}, 200);
        //               --^-- change here
    });
});
```

Comment: @Kevin : glad to help